# Is there a method to use rgba color [0, 15, 31, 0.4 ] to style a TD element in vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

I have this code and the goal to is style the TD element:

```
  <table >
      <tr>
        <td
          v-for="(color, index) in colors"
          :key="index"
          :style="{backgroundColor: color}"
        >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Where `color`  is an array of rgba  color like that  `[ [0, 15, 31, 0.4], [0, 20, 31, 0.4], .. ]`

The code is not working. It works only when I change the type of 'colors' array to HEX.

Comment: Would template literals help here? i.e. `:style="{backgroundColor: \`rgba(${color[0]}, $color[1], $color[2], $color[3])\`}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a method that returns a RGBA string, and then bind the method to the `style` attribute.

In the example below, which is slightly advanced, you use ES6's [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to generate the RGBA string you want:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td
      v-for="(color, index) in colors"
      :key="index"
      :style="tdCssStyle(color)"
    >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then in your component JS logic:

```
methods: {
    tdCssStyle: function(color) {
        const [r, g, b, a] = color;
        return {
            backgroundColor: `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a})`
        };
    }
}
```

Note: there is a typo in your `v-for` binding, you are missing the `in` keyword, i.e. it should be `(color, index) in colors`.

Proof-of-concept:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colors: [
      [0, 15, 31, 0.4],
      [0, 20, 31, 0.4]
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    tdCssStyle: function(color) {
      const [r, g, b, a] = color;
      return {
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a})`
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" :style="tdCssStyle(color)">
        {{ color }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the browser that the four numbers are an `rgba` value:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colors: [
      [230, 14, 43, 0.4],
      [0, 44, 131, 0.4]
    ]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(color, index) in colors" :key="index" :style="{backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.join(',')})` }">
       {{ color }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```